# Calling dlopen() twice on a dynamic library with undefined symbol

Tags: linux, error-handling, dlopen, shared-objects, dynamic-library

I'm opening a dynamic library with a call to `dlopen()`:

```
void *handle = dlopen("mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
if (!handle) 
    printf("%s", dlerror());
```

When this is called for a library which has an undefined symbol, the returned `handle` is NULL and I get the following printed in TTY:

> libmylib.so: undefined symbol: < the_symbol_name >

This is fine. But when I call this same code for the same library name for the second time, the returned `handle` is NOT NULL, and I get a crash when dereferencing it.

From the docs:

> If dlopen() fails for any reason, it returns NULL.

So why isn't NULL returned the second time?

Comment: Sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591389/dlopen-works-second-time-on-bad-shared-library-on-ubuntu-11-04-does-the-right-t?rq=1

Comment: @viraptor The link lacks a good answer though.

Comment: if you do get a stacktrace that ends in libc and have a minimal example, it could be worth reporting a bug upstream (glibc I assume?)